# MYSQL looping columns to change into a view

Tags: mysql

Bit of a strange one, looking for a way to convert a table to view but alter some columns in a stored proc

I could manually create the view with the adjustments, something like:

```
SELECT id,CASE WHEN address1 != '' THEN LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) END AS address1,
CASE WHEN address2 != '' THEN LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) END AS address2, CASE WHEN 
address3 != '' THEN LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) END AS address3,
town,county,postcode,country FROM address
```

but ideally want to loop through the table and only make the adjustments on those specific columns (in case the underlining structure changes, a new column is added)

Thinking of creating a lookup table with the info and then use dynamic statement to create the view so:
    lookup table

```
column_name   Code
address1      CASE WHEN address1 != '' THEN LEFT(MD5(RAND()),8) END AS address1
```

declare/prepare

set @View := (concat("CREATE View `DB_name`.`",tablename,"` as select (list of columns including the lookups changes from `DB_name`.`",tablename,"`"

Can't seem to find anything online to find a way of looping columns into a prepared statement, is this possible or just a waste of time????? (Due to restrictions has to be done in Mysql )

Comment: Manage to find a workaround solution, combined my lookup table to information_schema.columns, added a little case and then group_concat to get the string required, with the tablename as the loop

Comment: SET @code = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM 
    (SELECT IF(oc.columncode IS NULL,CONCAT('`',c.column_name,'`'), 
    oc.columncode) AS column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns c LEFT JOIN `lkp_table` oc ON 
    c.table_name = oc.tablename AND c.column_name = oc.column
    WHERE table_schema='DB_name' AND TABLE_NAME = tablename 
    ORDER BY ordinal_position)a) ;

Comment: SET @InsertView := CONCAT("CREATE View 
    `DB_name`.`",tablename,"` as select ",@code," from 
    `DB_name`.`",tablename,"`");                                                 
    PREPARE InsertView FROM @InsertView; 
    EXECUTE InsertView;